# Is it complusory to cancel the Alarm once its invoked?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-calendar

What's the difference between following lines

**(A)**

```
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

**(B)**

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

How important is to cancel the `Alarm` once alarm is invoked/fired? What happens if we don't cancel it?

**Code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Get the AlarmManager service
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerInMills, sender);
```

Comment: One *adds* 0 milliseconds, the other *sets* the millisecond field to 0, read the docs. Your question is also vague. How are you making this Alarm?

Comment: I am able to achieve the alarm invoked, so that's not an issue.. So both add and set have same result??

Comment: No, why would adding be the same as setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

[`Calendar#add()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) adds the amount specified to the field specified.

If you do

```
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
```

The instance of the Calendar will get an **increase** in the millisecond field by `1`. If the Calendar had `212` milliseconds, this method call would cause it to be `213` milliseconds.

[`Calendar#set()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29) sets the field to what you want.

If you do

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

And the Calendar has `212` milliseconds, this would cause it to be `0` milliseconds.

One method *adds*, the other *sets*

> How important is to cancel the Alarm once alarm is invoked/fired? What happens if we don't cancel it?

If you use just [`AlarmManager#set()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), it doesn't repeat, so you don't have to cancel anything *after* execution.

If you use [`AlarmManager#setRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), then you will have to cancel.

If you *don't* cancel, it keeps repeating, like the documentation and name imply.

All alarms will be erased upon a shutdown/reboot and will need to be recreated.

Comment: @user1967146 I touched upon the alarm cancellation, which is vague as it is. If you want a "full" answer, you will give me more details.

Comment: so it won't effect anything if we don't cancel the repeated alarm?

Comment: @user1967146 You're using `set()` there, so you don't need to cancel anything - the alarm won't repeat.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong about this. Cancel the alarm when you don't want it. Otherwise, if you set the alarm with a new intent later, you will get two alarm triggered eventually.

Comment: @ronak_jain cwhsu the only time you will have to cancel an alarm that uses `set()` is if you *haven't* executed the alarm yet and are using a completelt different `PendingIntent()`. But if your alarm already executed, cancelling it won't do a thing. I highly suggest you read the documentation I linked, it goes into more detail.

Comment: @cwhsu if the PendingIntents are **equal**, the Alarm will be replaced.

Comment: @A--C I know that happens but I am not sure whether it's Intent or PendingIntent causing the duplicated triggering. Thanks for the answer!